# $A $ is nonnegative ,$A$ has a nonnegative eigenvector then ${P^T}AP = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} B & C \\ 0 & D \\ \end{array}} \right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n$ is nonnegative(all $a_{ij}\ge0$).

Suppose $A$ has a nonnegative eigenvector(all entries$\ge0$ ) with $r ≥ 1$ positive entries and $n − r$ zero entries.

Why is there a permutation matrix $P$, such that ${P^T}AP = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   B & C  \\
   0 & D  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ is nonnegative,$B\in M_r$ , $D\in M_{n−r}$ , and $B$ has a positive eigenvector?

Comment: The natural approach seems to be permuting the rows and columns of $A$ so that the final $r$ rows and columns correspond to the positive entries of the hypothesized nonnegative eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x$ be the eigenvector. Find $P$ such that $Px= (x',0)^T$ with $x'>0$. Divide $PAP^T$ into the blocks
$$
\pmatrix{
B&C\\E&D
}
$$
and multiply the block matrices $PAP^T$ and $Px$.

That is, note that
$$
(PAP^T)(Px)=
\pmatrix{ Bx'\\ Ex'
}
$$.

Comment: How can divide $P^TAP$ into the blocks?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: (1) What is the use of $x$? where ${P^T}AP = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   B & C  \\
   0 & D  \\
\end{array}} \right)$.(2) Why has $B$  a positive eigenvector?

Comment: Oh, I see. $B$ is $r\times r$, and $D$ is $(n-r)\times(n-r)$. The key is to use block-matrix multiplication.

Comment: If ${P^T}AP = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   B & C  \\
   E & D  \\
\end{array}} \right)$, why should $E=0$?

Comment: See my edit. Note that $Ex'=0$.

Comment: Why is ${P^T}A{(x',0)^T} = Ax$ true?

Comment: I had a mistake before. Fixed it

Comment: Let $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{A_1}} & {{A_2}}  \\
   {{A_3}} & {{A_4}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)$. Can we say that $({P^T}AP)x\mathop  = \limits^? \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   *  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ or ${P^T}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{A_1}x'}  \\
   {{A_3}x'}  \\
\end{array}} \right)\mathop  = \limits^? \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   *  \\
   0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$?

Comment: Fixed again... It should be right this time. The idea is to use the fact that $x$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. Why has $B$ a positive eigenvector? Can we say that $B>0$?

Comment: $x'$ is an eigenvector of $B$. We *cannot* conclude that $B>0$.